# WEB increasing the space between letters

Tags: javascript, html, css, size

I may be barking up the wrong tree here but im looking for a solution to increase the width in a space for example the space bar on your keyboard or in html terms " ". I have tried a few ideas I had like adding 2 " " as well as using js to replace spaces with  tags adding css width property's. I have been also scouring the web for any css properties and found nothing. It would be great if anyone could share there knowledge and any ideas on how to solve this problem.
Thanks

image for reference

[image]

Comment: Do you letter-spacing or something else.

Comment: Yes that sounds about right "letter-spacing"

Comment: The width of any given character is determined by the font. If you want a wider space character then use a font with one.

Comment: Letter spacing controls the distance between *every* pair of characters, not the width of a space.

Comment: is there any other solution besides adding space in the font as i don't think i have skill to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to achieve this but it would involve wrapping all spaces in a tag like a `span`... might not be the best solution but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/unjLy1vr/

```
var sentences = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(var i=0;i<sentences.length;i++){
    sentences[i].innerHTML = sentences[i].innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '<span class="makeSpace"> </span>');
}

.makeSpace {
     letter-spacing: 15px;
}
```

---

**Update:-** you can use the `word-spacing` property:

http://jsfiddle.net/0m8nn6gx/

```
p {
     word-spacing: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use letter-spacing, you can set spacing whatever you want

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

or you can use thing like

```
<span style="space"></span>


.space { display: inline-block;
         width: 20px; }
```